# border bottom won't show on hover on bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

Border bottom won't show on hover on bootstrap navbar. I want it to show up on the bottom of the div in the navbar on hover.

```
.navbar-inverse {
    background-color: white;
}
.navbar-inverse {
    border-color: green
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: #0000EE;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus {
    background-color: #2BFF79
}
.dropdown-menu {
    background-color: #FFFFFF
}
.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover,
.dropdown-menu>li>a:focus {
    background-color: green;
}
.navbar-inverse {
    background-image: none;
}
.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover,
.dropdown-menu>li>a:focus {
    background-image: none;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand {
    color: #FFFFFF
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: green;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: "Arial Narrow", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
    color: green;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.dropdown-menu>li>a {
    color: #333333
}
.navbar-bottom {
    background-color: green;
}
.navbar-fixed-bottom {
    background-color: green;
}
ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: "Agency FB";
}
ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu a {
    color: green;
}
```

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle..

Comment: share a working code with needed HTML and CSS as well

Comment: over 500 lines of code. Simply not sure how to address that property in the bootstrap navbar.

Comment: share that much part..! only the nav section. and paste your CSS  or simply create a fiddle, Codepen or Snippet here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need use `border-bottom-color` or `border-bottom`

if `border-style` and `border-width` are already given then,

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom-color: #0000EE;
}
```

else

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #0000EE;
}
```

Comment: it's the 3rd line in your code. but it's better if you make a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) of your code

Comment: I answered your question based on the single rule set that you mentioned before your edit hoping that you figured out the source of the issue, but it seems you didnt. please do make a fiddle of your code so that we can check the issue